# Storekit: buying beginning event

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need get event when user entered correct password and buying process is begun. What delegate can tell me about this?

I need it to disable the interface to avoid double clicking Buy button.

Comment: there are different types of delegates, it all depends on your requirement!!! You can even create your own delegate to notify you about the correct password!!! You can also use text field delegate which is simple to use, and it will notify you when you entered correct password in textfield

Comment: You should read the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267) for details on the process.